# SQL Server 2008 R2 - How to unzip/decompress/extract files in BIDS Visual Studio 2008

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, extract, 7zip, bids

Building a SSIS package in BIDs, 2008 R2, and need to unzip the latest file from a zip folder on a weekly basis.  I've never used the script task and would like to utilize the .net framework (3.5 I think) to pick up the most current file from our drop folder (already created), unzip, and drop in an unzipped folder.  Archive used is 7-Zip 9.20.

Comment: What did you try and why do you use Visual Studio 2008? Visual Studio 2017 will be released on March 7 2017. Show also your code.

Comment: add you related work so far if you want to get help

Comment: @JeroenHeier why not? Not everyone want to pay for new releases.